# Can microsoft compiler cl.exe compile to OMF object type instead COFF?

Tags: cl, coff, omf

I want to link object file created by `cl.exe` with another object file which is in format `OMF` using third party linker. That third party linker does not accept `COFF` format. I want to know if `cl` can make objects in `OMF` format?